# Why is the output of the following code 1 and not 0?

Tags: java, integer

```
    @Test
    public void test(){
        Map<String, Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
        a.put("x", new Integer(0));
        Integer i = a.get("x");
        a.put("x", i++);
        i = a.get("x");
        a.put("x", i++);
        i = a.get("x");
        a.put("x", i++);
        System.err.println(i);
    }
```

The output of the above code is 1 and not 0. I cannot figure out why. Can someone explain whats going on?
Some byte code optimizations by Java lead to this state?

Comment: You increment, so why do you expect 0 to be printed?

Comment: Please make use of a debugger. That's an effective way to understand how a code snippet works.

Answer (score 4):

Because `i++` returns `i` **before incrementing** `i`. See my comments:

```
Map<String, Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
a.put("x", new Integer(0)); // x=0
Integer i = a.get("x");     // i=0
a.put("x", i++);            // x=0, i=1
i = a.get("x");             // i=0
a.put("x", i++);            // x=0, i=1
i = a.get("x");             // i=0
a.put("x", i++);            // x=0, i=1
System.err.println(i);
```

Here's the relevant part from the [documentation of unary operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html):

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or after (postfix) the operand. The code `result++;` and `++result;` will both end in result being incremented by one.
>
> The only difference is that the prefix version (`++result`) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas **the postfix version (`result++`) evaluates to the original value.**
>
> If you are just performing a simple increment/decrement, it doesn't really matter which version you choose. But if you use this operator in part of a larger expression, the one that you choose may make a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be one. Last statement is `a.put("x", i++);` so you put the value `0` into your `Map` but then you increment `i`. If your last statement was `i = a.get("x");` you would get `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You use *post-increment*, so the value of `i` is read first, then incremented.

```
 @Test
public void test(){
    Map<String, Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
    a.put("x", new Integer(0));
    Integer i = a.get("x"); // i is 0
    a.put("x", i++); // x = 0; then i increment
    i = a.get("x"); // i is reset to 0
    a.put("x", i++); // x = 0; then i increment
    i = a.get("x"); // i is reset to 0
    a.put("x", i++); // x = 0; then i increment
    System.err.println(i); // i == 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explained inline:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    Map<String, Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
    a.put("x", new Integer(0)); // Store Integer(0)
    Integer i = a.get("x");     // Get it
    a.put("x", i++);            // Unbox it, rebox it, store it again (still 0); increment it afterward
    i = a.get("x");             // Same again
    a.put("x", i++);            // ...
    i = a.get("x");             // ...
    a.put("x", i++);            // Unbox it, rebox it, store it again (still 0); increment it afterward 
    System.err.println(i);      // Show it; contains the *incremented* value
}
```

Since the value stored is always 0, and you get it at the end and increment it, you end up with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Lets go through this step by step:

```
    Integer i = a.get("x");
```

i is 0

```
    a.put("x", i++);
```

the "x" in the map doesnt change because you set it to i (=0) and increment after setting it.

```
    i = a.get("x");
```

Again i gets set to 0 since thats still whats stored in "x"

```
    a.put("x", i++);
```

Same thing as above, i gets set to one only after setting "x" to 0

```
    i = a.get("x");
```

i =0

```
    a.put("x", i++);
```

Now i is 1 and you print it

```
    System.err.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement increase i by 1 resulting i = 1.